# Ti:Sapphire Laser/Regenerative Amplifier Construction

Tags: optics, laser, photonics

I'm interested in exploring air breakdown in the femtosecond regime.

I'd like to generate a beam with a pulse-width of <30fs, with a peak intensity of around 0.5-1mJ/pulse, a repetition rate of at least 1kHz, and tunable wavelength.

For the given beam specs:

- Can I use an easily available solid-state continuous wave laser as a pump? Should I be using a pulsed laser to do it?
- It looks like I can pick up a Ti:Sapphire crystal for around $400. I think I can construct the optics to build a passive amplifier - is it as straightforward as it looks? Should I be using prisms or gratings?
- Would a passive amplifier meet the beam requirements above, or would I need to consider building a CPA laser amplifier? What's the threshold for switching to CPA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mJ-class amplifier for a 30 fs pulse will require CPA and a pulsed pump laser. I haven’t built one of these myself, so I’m not familiar with the details of when each of these becomes necessary. However, I’ve used a couple and am familiar with the commercial market, and that’s my determination. I urge you to look at what’s commercially available to see what’s (easily) possible; if you could build a 1 mJ, 1 kHz, 30 fs laser amplifier that easily, it would be a product.

A non-exhaustive list of complications I thought off the top of my head that you could keep in mind:

- Multi-pass geometry for both pump and seed: Your amplifier crystal will not fully absorb the pump, nor will the seed fully exhaust the energy in a single pass, necessitating a somewhat complicated alignment. As an example, the most recent amplifier I’ve used has a two-pass pump geometry and a 9-pass (!) seed geometry in the first stage to get the energy up to ~1.5 mJ. A regenerative configuration is an alternative.
- Pump pulse synchronization and pulse picking: To get the gain you need, you’ll have to go with a pulsed pump laser. That same first stage amplifier uses a ~10 W average power 1 kHz multi-ns pump (so, 10 mJ). You need to synchronize the pump pulses to your seed pulse train. Since your seed is likely much higher in repetition rate, later you’d use a pulse picker to choose the largest-amplified seed pulse and discard the rest.
- Crystal cooling: You’ll need to cool your crystal (which is absorbing ~10 W of heat).
- Limited tunablility: You’re not going to have a lot of tunability. At least, if you do tune your seed away from the peak gain, you won’t get nearly 1 mJ of energy. The standard solution is to build an OPA following the amplifier to provide broad tunability. In any case, your pulses will have something like 40 nm bandwidth to get the short duration.
- Dispersion management: As I mentioned before, CPA will be necessary, but even if you didn’t use it, there would be a lot of dispersion in the multi-pass geometry. So you need prisms or gratings to compress your resulting pulses regardless.

Good luck!

Comment: This is awesome, thanks for your thoughtful answer. I think building a pulsed CPA is likely outside out of my abilities (I had hoped I'd be able to do it with a passive multi-pass). As you pointed out; I couldn't find any simple table-top product with these specs (though many at 1-10% of the power), and I think this explains why.

I might ask my local university (London) to see if they'd be willing to show off their kit for an enthusiastic amateur; it's very difficult to wrap one's head around the practicalities of high-power laser optics from reading papers alone.

Thanks again!

Comment: @chrism2671 I’m sure you’ll find some graduate student excited to show you around! That’ll give you a good sense of the complexity. That said, CPA, while a Nobel-worthy idea, is not actually difficult to implement. Since you’ll need a pulse compressor anyway, you just use another one at the beginning in inverse configuration to stretch.

Comment: @chrism2671 also, as an enthusiastic amateur with (apparently) a budget, do you happen to already possess the myriad peripheral instruments you’d need? Power meter, spectrometer, oscilloscope, autocorrelator, etc.?

Comment: @chrism2671 ...not to mention the Ti:Sapphire oscillator?

Comment: I've got access to the electronics stuff (oscilloscope, wave generators etc) but not to any specific optics stuff. I can afford the bits at the ebay level; not at the 5-figure+ level. It does seem like a lot of optics cash goes into the mountings etc.

Comment: What I'm really trying to do is determine why, in this paper, they stopped at the point they did: https://sci-hub.scihubtw.tw/10.1145/2850414. It looks like they had something interesting, and the next steps would be to try and reduce the pulse power to the lowest possible threshold, and then work on broadening the scanning range.

Comment: Well, rather than speculate, I've reached out to the paper's authors and asked. Thanks for the push, and I really appreciate your insight.